# Algorithm for enumerating all possible ways a rectangle can be split into n smaller rectangles

Tags: algorithm, optimization

See title for question. The only other limitation is that the smaller rectangles have to be formed by diving bigger rectangles in half. I have attached the result for n=3 and n=4 below. Hopefully this will suffice to explain the meaning of my questions.

Currently, I have an inefficient recursive algorithm that divides each rectangle horizontally and vertically, and keeps track of all possible combinations in an array. I do not like this algorithm. It is polynomial time, seems unnecessarily complicated and gives me duplicates, as seen in the n=4 picture (hint: look for four equal quadrants)

I was wondering if there might be a better solution to this? I was expermenting with using a 4-ary tree (where each child gets a vertical or horizontal piece), and am able to construct the tree but getting all possible combinations from the tree seems to be eluding me. I'll post my tree boiler plate code below:

```
class Node:
    #value is an tuple (x0,y0,x1,y1)
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.horizontal = []
        self.vertical = []
        self.value = value
    def createTree(depth, currDepth, node):
        if currDepth == depth:
            return
        node.horizontal.append(Node(getLeftRect(node.value)))
        node.horizontal.append(Node(getRightRect(node.value)))
        node.vertical.append(Node(getTopRect(node.value)))
        node.vertical.append(Node(getBotRect(node.value)))
        createTree(depth, currDepth+1, node.horizontal[0])
        createTree(depth, currDepth+1, node.horizontal[1])
        createTree(depth, currDepth+1, node.vertical[0])
        createTree(depth, currDepth+1, node.vertical[1])
```

Any suggestions/help is welcome!

Note: This is not coursework. I'm trying to make a UI for a custom virtual monitor tool I'm working on.

[image]

[image: n=4]

Comment: You will get more views of your question if you add the language tag.

Comment: There is an infinite number of ways that a rectangle can be split into `n` smaller rectangles. What are the other restrictions?

Comment: @JimMischel updated the question. Thanks for pointing that out. Please see the images attached for a better sense of what I meant

Comment: You actually want the visuals, right? Not the count of how many ways?

Comment: @גלעדברקן Yes, that is correct. I need the coordinates of the resulting rectangles for each permutation so I can display them on my UI

Comment: Your examples seem like squares but you mean any kind of rectangle?

Comment: Yes any kind of rectangle should work. A square is a special kind of rectangle after all

Comment: btw http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1116/number-of-ways-to-partition-a-rectangle-into-n-sub-rectangles

Comment: (might be a mute point, given David's great answer, but i added my own recursive version.)

Answer (score 6):

One strategy is, when we cut vertically, don't let both the left half and the right half have a horizontal cut. This involves some case analysis.

In Python 3, we first have data types to represent subdivided rectangles.

```
import collections

H = collections.namedtuple('H', ('top', 'bottom'))  # horizontal cut
V = collections.namedtuple('V', ('left', 'right'))  # vertical cut
W = collections.namedtuple('W', ())                 # whole rectangle
```

Here are the generators.

```
def generate(n):
    assert isinstance(n, int) and n >= 0
    yield from generate_with_horizontal(n)
    yield from generate_without_horizontal(n)


def generate_with_horizontal(n):
    assert isinstance(n, int) and n >= 0
    for k in range(n):
        for top in generate(k):
            for bottom in generate(n - 1 - k):
                yield H(top, bottom)


def generate_without_horizontal(n):
    assert isinstance(n, int) and n >= 0
    if n == 0:
        yield W()
    for k in range(n):
        for left in generate_with_horizontal(k):
            for right in generate_without_horizontal(n - 1 - k):
                yield V(left, right)
        for left in generate_without_horizontal(k):
            for right in generate(n - 1 - k):
                yield V(left, right)
```

Comment: It's amazing how you came up with such beautiful looking code! It took me a while to get it (I'm not very familiar with python/generators yet) but I get the gist of the logic. Thanks!

Comment: Does this avoid duplicates after 5, 7, 9 ... steps too? I just realised that the cross after 3 steps is only the first of a number of problems. See the additional image in my answer.

Comment: @m69 Yes. Essentially we define a canonical order in which to make cuts, where we make a horizontal cut first if we can and a vertical cut otherwise. The point of `generate_without_horizontal` is that it ensures at least one unbroken vertical slab, to justify the vertical cut at the root of the cut tree.

Comment: Could you post the number of unique solutions for up to 8 or so rectangles?

Comment: @m69 [1, 2, 8, 39, 212, 1232, 7492, 47082, 303336, 1992826]

Answer (score 5):

Idea for a recursive or tree-building algorithm that avoids duplicates:
You start off with a rectangle, and a number of times it has to be divided. Divide it in both directions, and decrease the number by one, and then for each division (vertical and horizontal), partition the number over the two parts.

[image: rectangle divider]

This method results in 39 divisions when dividing into 4 parts (and 1 duplicate).

The only duplicate I haven't been able to avoid is the cross. Using this method, whenever you have a rectangle that needs to be divided a further 3 or more times, you're going to run into the cross twice. So you'll have to add some additional check for that.

You'll also notice that the 4 groups of 8 solutions resulting from an initial `2,0` partitioning are 90°, 180° and 270° rotations of each other. And the 2 groups of 4 solutions resulting from an initial `1,1` partitioning are 90° rotations of each other. So you can solve only one group, and then rotate to get all the solutions.

---

It seems the duplicates are going to be harder to avoid with this method than I first thought. If you add 2 more divisions, the seemingly very different `L3 R1` and `T2 B2` main options lead to several duplicates 4 steps further:

[image: rectangle division duplicates]

As David Eisenstat mentions in his answer, you can avoid cross doubles by only allowing both halves of a rectangle to be divided in one order (e.g. first vertical, then horizontal) but not the other. This means that when processing a rectangle, you have to be aware where its "other half" is, and whether and how that half has been divided; so that complicates the code needed to use this method.

Comment: I was doing something very similar to your method! How are you avoiding the other 2 duplicates though? If we assume n=4, then you should get 2 combinations with equal quadrants when you start  by dividing horizontally, and 2 when you start by dividing vertically. Or did I misunderstand your method?

Comment: @Sid I've edited the image, because I was skipping a step. You'll see that 2 of the 6 main options only lead to 2 and then 4, instead of 4 and then 8, solutions. That is where your 8 additional duplicates would be.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a recursion in Python that saves the tree as a dictionary where the children are indexed as `2i` and `2i + 1`. I tried to implement David Eisenstat's suggestion about avoiding a horizontal split on both sides of a vertical split (the number of results seems to correspond with the ones he provided in the comments).

```py
from sets import Set

def f(n):
  results = []

  def _f(n,result,indexes):
    if n == 1:
      results.append(result)
      return

    for i in list(indexes):
      indexes.remove(i)

      parent = i // 2
      sibling = i - 1 if i & 1 else i + 1 
      left = 2 * i
      right = 2 * i + 1

      # add horizontal split

      if not (False if i < 2 else result[sibling] == 'H' and result[parent] == 'V'):
        result_h = result.copy()
        indexes_h = indexes.copy()

        result_h[i] = 'H'

        result_h[left] = result_h[right] = 'W'
        indexes_h.add(left)
        indexes_h.add(right)

        _f(n - 1, result_h, indexes_h)

      # add vertical split

      result_v = result.copy()
      indexes_v = indexes.copy()

      result_v[i] = 'V'

      result_v[left] = result_v[right] = 'W'
      indexes_v.add(left)
      indexes_v.add(right)

      _f(n - 1, result_v, indexes_v)

  _f(n,{1:1},Set([1]))
  return results
```

Results for `f(4)`:

```
{1: 'H', 2: 'H', 3: 'H', 4: 'W', 5: 'W', 6: 'W', 7: 'W'}
{1: 'H', 2: 'H', 3: 'V', 4: 'W', 5: 'W', 6: 'W', 7: 'W'}
{1: 'H', 2: 'H', 3: 'W', 4: 'H', 5: 'W', 8: 'W', 9: 'W'}
{1: 'H', 2: 'H', 3: 'W', 4: 'V', 5: 'W', 8: 'W', 9: 'W'}
{1: 'H', 2: 'H', 3: 'W', 4: 'W', 5: 'H', 10: 'W', 11: 'W'}
{1: 'H', 2: 'H', 3: 'W', 4: 'W', 5: 'V', 10: 'W', 11: 'W'}
{1: 'H', 2: 'V', 3: 'H', 4: 'W', 5: 'W', 6: 'W', 7: 'W'}
{1: 'H', 2: 'V', 3: 'V', 4: 'W', 5: 'W', 6: 'W', 7: 'W'}
{1: 'H', 2: 'V', 3: 'W', 4: 'H', 5: 'W', 8: 'W', 9: 'W'}
{1: 'H', 2: 'V', 3: 'W', 4: 'V', 5: 'W', 8: 'W', 9: 'W'}
{1: 'H', 2: 'V', 3: 'W', 4: 'W', 5: 'H', 10: 'W', 11: 'W'}
{1: 'H', 2: 'V', 3: 'W', 4: 'W', 5: 'V', 10: 'W', 11: 'W'}
{1: 'H', 2: 'W', 3: 'H', 6: 'H', 7: 'W', 12: 'W', 13: 'W'}
{1: 'H', 2: 'W', 3: 'H', 6: 'V', 7: 'W', 12: 'W', 13: 'W'}
{1: 'H', 2: 'W', 3: 'H', 6: 'W', 7: 'H', 14: 'W', 15: 'W'}
{1: 'H', 2: 'W', 3: 'H', 6: 'W', 7: 'V', 14: 'W', 15: 'W'}
{1: 'H', 2: 'W', 3: 'V', 6: 'H', 7: 'W', 12: 'W', 13: 'W'}
{1: 'H', 2: 'W', 3: 'V', 6: 'V', 7: 'W', 12: 'W', 13: 'W'}
{1: 'H', 2: 'W', 3: 'V', 6: 'W', 7: 'H', 14: 'W', 15: 'W'}
{1: 'H', 2: 'W', 3: 'V', 6: 'W', 7: 'V', 14: 'W', 15: 'W'}
{1: 'V', 2: 'H', 3: 'V', 4: 'W', 5: 'W', 6: 'W', 7: 'W'}
{1: 'V', 2: 'H', 3: 'W', 4: 'H', 5: 'W', 8: 'W', 9: 'W'}
{1: 'V', 2: 'H', 3: 'W', 4: 'V', 5: 'W', 8: 'W', 9: 'W'}
{1: 'V', 2: 'H', 3: 'W', 4: 'W', 5: 'H', 10: 'W', 11: 'W'}
{1: 'V', 2: 'H', 3: 'W', 4: 'W', 5: 'V', 10: 'W', 11: 'W'}
{1: 'V', 2: 'V', 3: 'H', 4: 'W', 5: 'W', 6: 'W', 7: 'W'}
{1: 'V', 2: 'V', 3: 'V', 4: 'W', 5: 'W', 6: 'W', 7: 'W'}
{1: 'V', 2: 'V', 3: 'W', 4: 'H', 5: 'W', 8: 'W', 9: 'W'}
{1: 'V', 2: 'V', 3: 'W', 4: 'V', 5: 'W', 8: 'W', 9: 'W'}
{1: 'V', 2: 'V', 3: 'W', 4: 'W', 5: 'H', 10: 'W', 11: 'W'}
{1: 'V', 2: 'V', 3: 'W', 4: 'W', 5: 'V', 10: 'W', 11: 'W'}
{1: 'V', 2: 'W', 3: 'H', 6: 'H', 7: 'W', 12: 'W', 13: 'W'}
{1: 'V', 2: 'W', 3: 'H', 6: 'V', 7: 'W', 12: 'W', 13: 'W'}
{1: 'V', 2: 'W', 3: 'H', 6: 'W', 7: 'H', 14: 'W', 15: 'W'}
{1: 'V', 2: 'W', 3: 'H', 6: 'W', 7: 'V', 14: 'W', 15: 'W'}
{1: 'V', 2: 'W', 3: 'V', 6: 'H', 7: 'W', 12: 'W', 13: 'W'}
{1: 'V', 2: 'W', 3: 'V', 6: 'V', 7: 'W', 12: 'W', 13: 'W'}
{1: 'V', 2: 'W', 3: 'V', 6: 'W', 7: 'H', 14: 'W', 15: 'W'}
{1: 'V', 2: 'W', 3: 'V', 6: 'W', 7: 'V', 14: 'W', 15: 'W'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it looks like there is a few ways to generate all the non-isomorphic possibilities, so my suggestion would be:

1. Generate them all for some number of monitors.
2. Remove duplicates and store results.
3. When you need them, read from file.

The thing is, unless you need the result for large inputs (say 6-10) you don't want to generate them on-the-fly. Even if you did want to show the results for this size of partition, it would surely be much larger than you could usefully display to the user!

That said, if you do want to generate non-isomorphic representatives of these structures, there is some interesting research on 'sliceable duals' - see for example [this masters thesis](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-319-27261-0_38) by Vincent Kusters. Note though that your structures are more general as they include partitions that meet at a four-join.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to your question, but you should consider it:

Be very careful while using a recursive algorithm for counting the number of partitions for n>4. The reason is that we can have some partitions in which merging NO two rectangular ends up in another rectangular. For instance, for five partitions, consider the following:

[The picture is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26erc.png)

I think the algorithms suggested above miss all partitions similar to this one.